# Update object from partial object in Scala

Tags: scala

New to Scala, I'm trying to do the TypeScript equivalent of following code

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

function update(p: Person, partial: Partial<Person>): Person {
  return { ...p, ...partial }
}

const p = new Person("xyz", 20)
update(p, { name: "abc" }) // { name: "abc", age: 20 }
```

In reality this `Person` can have many fields and update only a subset of it, what's be best way to do it? should I use lower type bound `U >: Person` and check each field exist and assign?

```
def update[U >: Person](p: Person, partial: U): Person {
  p.copy(???)
}
```

Comment: Do you really need that? If so, how generic must it be?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I feel it's quit common practice in JS world, for example, if I have a `TodoListItem` I want to update anything but `id` and `createdAt` I can do `const update = (partial: Partial<TodoListItem>)  => { ...item, ...partial, id: item.id, createdAt: item.createdAt }`. The argument is any subset properties of TodoListItem and the update RULE is enforced by this function.

Comment: Sure, and is common practice to use `goto` in assembler, so should we implement it in **Scala**? Do you have a real use case / meta-problem that you are trying to solve or are only curious? If the latter, then the quick answer is that the solution would be done with **Shapeless** and is quite complex, if the former, are you sure this is the best solution?

Comment: I'm just curious, thank you for enlighten me!

Comment: You might want to take a look at Monocle lens and see if it fits your need: https://www.optics.dev/Monocle/